# How to Run the Procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here the Package..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE G_PKG_REFCUR AS
    TYPE rcDataCursor IS REF CURSOR;
END;
```

Let's consider the PROC..

```
Create procedure gokul_proc(
    pId in number,
    pName in varchar2,
    OutCur OUT G_PKG_REFCUR.rcDataCursor ) is
BEGIN
    Open OutCur For
        select * from gokul_table ob 
        where ob.active_staus-'Y' AND ob.id=pId AND ob.name=pNname;
END;
```

Here is my question: How can I execute this procedure?

If there isn't an OutCur parameter, then I can execute like this..

```
EXEC gokul_proc(1,'GOKUL');
```

but, the problem is OutCur. I don't know which value to pass here.

For example

```
EXEC gokul_proc(1,'GOKUL', ??????);
```

I just need to know what value to pass as a argument for the procedure.

Comment: Though I fixed some of the formatting, consider editing your question so that it's uses more proper English, rather than "duno", "pls", etc.

Comment: on a side note, I think you've mistyped a "-" in the where clause - e.g. ob.active_staus='Y'

Answer (score 21):

In SQL Plus:

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC gokul_proc(1,'GOKUL', :rc);
print rc
```